# Saving empty dir list with path windows cmd to a text file

Tags: windows, cmd

I know this is dumb question but due to lack of my DOS knowledge i have facing trouble. I have a dir which have more than 98000 subdirs but many of them dont have any files i just want to list them with path

for now i am using this batch file

```
 @echo off
 for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (
 dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA 
 )
```

this is exactly does what i just want but the problem its not saving the list to a text file as lots of lots of dirs are empty cant copy from the cmd i tried with this code just modifying

```
@echo off
for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (
dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA >epty.txt
)
```

but its just save one line not a list. what i want need just all list to be printed to a text file of this function.

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try redirecting the whole output from this script to a text file when you call it. E.g. if the first script you gave was saved to a file named script.cmd in your current working directory then you could call it from the command prompt using:

```
script.cmd > output.txt
```